# I have a txt file and I need to invert its pair of bytes in linux terminal

Tags: unix

I have a txt file and I need to invert its pair of bytes in linux terminal to reveal a code.
I'm new to unix and can't find a way to do this. I know it has something to do with dd command but i'm not sure.

this text is in the txt file

```
åæ€ ±ã nUv eiliÃ t©na
gèé£ŸèãŒU eng eroniullðe žuq ilpnoeg
,°æãŽ®é ³eLb urtid  e'laeðu
```

Answer (score 1):

The following `dd` command will swap every two bytes from the string:

```
# dd conv=swab <<< "U eng eroniull e "
 Une grenouille
```

You can also achieve the same result with:

```
# iconv -f UTF16BE -t UTF16LE <<< "U eng eroniull e "
 Une grenouille
```

I only used a small decipherable part of your string which is probably UTF-8 encoded originally (and swapping bytes of a UTF-8 encoded string results in invalid characters).